# Edit Json file in Windows Phone8.1 programmatically

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

```
{
"DrinksItems": [
    {
        "UniqueId": "Drinks-Item-1",
        "Title": "After Five",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/Drinks/AfterFive.png",
        "Description": "An After Five is a popular shooter that is often ...",
        "Ingredients": "1/2 oz (15ml) coffee liqueur",
        "Alcohol": "8.89",
        "Vodka": false,
        "Gin": false,
        "Whisky": false,
        "Beer": false,
        "Rum": false,
        "Wine": false,
        "Brandy": false,
        "Tequila": false,
        "Favorite": false,
        "Popular": false,
        "Glass": "Shot",
        "Category": "Creamy Sour-Cream drink"
    },
```

I want after button click change Favorite from false to true in JSON file. How I can do this ??

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, obviously, without the slightest background on what else you're doing, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: I want after click buttton on Item on List View change in JSON file "Favorite": false on "Favorite": true, I know how read from JSON but I don;t know how i can edit JSON file (if i must read all json file change favorite property and write all json file ?? but i think it is very time-consuming)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about a JSON file. You can't just update a single value like you can in a database. It is just a text file, so yes you have to read it all, update it, and save it just like any other text file.